# Two Button invokes same function

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I need to call the same function with two different button. This function contains a call to another function which expect a Bool value but connecting the two button graphically to the code I can't distinguish the two different calls to that function. For this reason I have created two identical functions for passing different Bool value. I hope in a your answer. Best regard to all. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I think you have two buttons into view and you want to connect that two buttons with same function so you can do that like this ways first create a function for the first button.

[image]

after that you can connect this function with another button like this way :

[image]

So this way you can create a same function for two different buttons.

**Edit For this answer** :

You can give different name for both buttons like `Button 1` and `Button 2`

after that you can do it like this way :

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

var button1 : Bool = Bool()
var button2 : Bool = Bool()

@IBAction func ButtonTapped(sender: UIButton) {
    if sender.titleLabel?.text == "Button 1"{
        button1 = true
        println("Button 1 Tapped")
        println(button1)
    }
    if sender.titleLabel?.text == "Button 2"{
        button2 = true
        println("Button 2 tapped")
        println(button2)
    }

}
```